# TinyMCE select text and activate link dialogue with javascript

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I'm trying to write an automated (using cucumber/capybara/selenium) test that will select some text in a tinymce box, click the link button, and open the link selection page.

But the link button only becomes active when some text is selected...so round one:

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.select(tinyMCE.activeEditor.dom.select('p')[0]);
```

This selects the text of the first paragraph (good enough for my purposes) but the link box is still disabled.  So then I tried to manually activate it:

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.controlManager.setActive('link', true);
```

This still didn't enable the link button.  As a last ditch effort, I tried to modify the classes:

```
$("#mce_generic_html_link").removeClass("mceButtonDisabled");
$("#mce_generic_html_link").addClass("mceButtonEnabled");
```

But that didn't help either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my problem:

`tinymce.activeEditor.nodeChanged();`

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to enable the button:

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.controlManager.get('link').setDisabled(false)
```