# TinyMCE select text and activate link dialogue with javascript

Tags: jquery, tinymce, hyperlink

This is excellent [TinyMCE select text and activate link dialogue with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5917349/tinymce-select-text-and-activate-link-dialogue-with-javascript)

However is there a jquery version?

Something like..

```
tinyMCE.get('style_editor_content').activeEditor.nodeChanged();
```

Regards

Comment: what should 'style_editor_content' refer to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, using `tinymce.get` you can only get tinymce editor instances.

Comment: This worked,

    tinyMCE.get('style_editor_content').setContent('');
    tinyMCE.get('style_editor_content').execCommand('mceInsertContent',false,'<p id="ins_link">test</p>');
    tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.select(tinyMCE.activeEditor.dom.select('p')[0]); 
    tinyMCE.activeEditor.nodeChanged(); 
    tinyMCE.get('style_editor_content').execCommand('mceDAdvLink');

Comment: if 'style_editor_content' is your editor instance id, you may use tinyMCE.get('style_editor_content').nodeChanged();